# Vectorized lookup of MySQL, and add to DataFrame

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Go through a DataFrame, that contains Columns 'Col1' and 'Col2'
2. Take each row in 'Col1', Search MySQL db using that value
3. Replace the value on the same row in 'Col2' with the result

I'm leaning towards a For loop approach, but is there a faster vectorized approach. Rough code I'm using thus far:

```
    rsp_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(raw_data_path))
cur = mydb.cursor()

for x in rsp_df['Col1']:
    query = ("SELECT stuff FROM some-table WHERE Asin = '%s'" % str(x))
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchone()
    print rows
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider merging the MySQL query with the Pandas dataframe by importing the query into a separate dataframe. This way you match across all cases at once without looping and any conditional changes to columns can be done in one call.

Below is a `left` join merge to keep all records in *rsp_df* matched or not. Missing *stuff* from mydf denotes unmatched records. Then you can replace *Col2* with needed *result* (which I am not sure what you refer to as *result*, possibly a column in query's *stuff*):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pwd@localhost/database')

mydf = pd.read_sql("SELECT stuff FROM some-table", con=engine)

merged_df = pd.merge(rsp_df, mydf, left_on=['Col1'], right_on=['Asin'], how='left')

mergedf.loc[pd.notnull(mergedf['Asin']), 'Col2'] = mergedf['result']
```